# How to format two different size arrays together in a table in python

Tags: python, arrays, sorting, formatting

I am new to python so this could be a silly question.
I am trying to format two arrays in an easy to read table.
I am hoping to get a table that looks like this

```
Position   Time
[1 2 3]    [100]
[3 4 5]    [200]
[6 7 8]    [300]
```

etc

The positions are stored in an array and the times are stored in an array. All help is appreciated

I have tried using the NumPy concatenate command however it does not work as the dimensions do not match.
I have also tried using the tabulate command

`print(tabulate([positions, times], headers=['Position', 'Time']))`

however this does not provide any meaningful results

Comment: can u share sample array

Comment: What do you mean "this does not provide any meaningful results"?  (Also, the first argument to `tabulate` is (typically) a list of rows, it looks like you're trying to give it columns.)

Answer (score 0):

if you want to do it on your own, you could try something similar :

```
t1 = [[1,2,3],[3,4,5],[6,7,8]]
t2 = [100,200,300]

ml = max(len(repr(i)) for i in t1)
st = "%" + str(ml) + "s [%s]"
print(("%" + str(ml) + "s %s") % ("Position", "Time"))

for i,j in zip(t1, t2):
    print(st % (repr(i), j))
```

Result:

```
 Position Time
[1, 2, 3] [100]
[3, 4, 5] [200]
[6, 7, 8] [300]
```

But beware that this is only a toy example :), not for production purposes ...